# Connect 5-10 Bluetooth headphones at one time?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I'm trying to figure out a way to connect multiple sets of bluetooth headphones to a home theater PC. Is there a device out there that does this? I have search high and low. I found a BT Splitter but that only splits one connection into two.

The goal is have a movie playing where multiple people can listen to it via headphones, at various volumes. I.E. 110% for me, 50% for my wife, 235% for my mom, etc.

Do I just get a bunch of bluetooth transmitters and connect them to a USB hub?

Comment: They make infrared headphones for this... cheap

Comment: VBAN Receptor lite for iOS/Android might be an alternative to send audio to mobile device through WIFI Point (use VBAN-Spot application to send audio to all connected devices) . All is free. download and more info there: http://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/vban.htm

Comment: @appleoddity i looked aroun, are there any leaders in this space? They all seem kind of junky.

Comment: @user258609 this does look like a viable option. Might be a pain to have this downloaded and running on everyones phone. Ideal user experience would be to just have headphones ready to go at anytime

Comment: You have a choice of infrared or RF. Shopping suggestions are off topic, but I found this article that seems to do a good review: http://m.thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-wireless-home-theater-headphones/